# How to convert 10bit unsigned bytearray to uint16 bytearray in C?

Tags: c

I have an img in binary format format.
Each pixel is 10bit.

They are putted consecutively, like [9-2] in first byte and [1:0] in second byte.
Where 9 IS MSB bit, 0 - LSB.
How to convert them to 16bit array?

E.g:
Store like 8 bit:

```
0b10000011,
0b10101100,
0b10011001,
0b11000000,
0b10101000,
```

Actual data which contains real pixels and which I want convert to 16bit:

```
0b1000001110,
0b1011001001,
0b1001110000,
0b0010101000,
```

Comment: 1. Extract bits number 10-2 from input[0] and put in output[0]. 2. Extract bits number 2-1 from input[1] and put it at bit positions 8-7 in output[1]. 3. Extract bits number 10-4 from input[2] and put at bit positions 6-1 in output[1]. Etc. Etc. What have you tried? What exactly are you having problem with?

Comment: I had optimization issue, I need to make it as fast as possible.. mayve by storing some table or similar

Comment: You need specify that, in your question. Please post your attempt. What optimization issue? What architecture are you using? What compiler, compiler version and options are using? Are you interested in a portable solution? Are GNU extensions ok? What research did you? What did your research resulted in and why is it unsatisfactory? Specifying such things will allow others to answer you appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to convert data like this

```
img[0] = AAAAAAAA
img[1] = AABBBBBB
img[2] = BBBBCCCC
img[3] = CCCCCCDD
img[4] = DDDDDDDD
```

to data like this:

```
array[0] = 000000AAAAAAAAAA
array[1] = 000000BBBBBBBBBB
array[2] = 000000CCCCCCCCCC
array[3] = 000000DDDDDDDDDD
```

It can be done like this:

```
array[0] = ((img[0] << 2) | (img[1] >> 6)) & 0x3ff;
array[1] = ((img[1] << 4) | (img[2] >> 4)) & 0x3ff;
array[2] = ((img[2] << 6) | (img[3] >> 2)) & 0x3ff;
array[3] = ((img[3] << 8) |  img[4]      ) & 0x3ff;
```

To convert multiple blocks, for loop is useful like this:

```
for (int i = 0; (i + 1) * 5 <= num_of_bytes_in_img; i++) {
    array[i * 4 + 0] = ((img[i * 5 + 0] << 2) | (img[i * 5 + 1] >> 6)) & 0x3ff;
    array[i * 4 + 1] = ((img[i * 5 + 1] << 4) | (img[i * 5 + 2] >> 4)) & 0x3ff;
    array[i * 4 + 2] = ((img[i * 5 + 2] << 6) | (img[i * 5 + 3] >> 2)) & 0x3ff;
    array[i * 4 + 3] = ((img[i * 5 + 3] << 8) |  img[i * 5 + 4]      ) & 0x3ff;
}
```

(this loop won't convert last a few bytes, so you should treat them separately or add padding to img not to read out-of-range while using this loop to end of the image)

Comment: Thank you! Can it be done faster, via storing in table e.g

Comment: @delkov: probably not.  You'd need four tables indexed by the combination of two bytes for picking out pixel 0..3 from the sequence of bytes (so `table0` would be indexed by `(byte0 << 8) | byte1` to pick out the zeroth byte; `table1` and `(byte1 << 8) | byte2`, etc).  No pixel requires more than two consecutive bytes.  That would require 65,536 entries per table, and 4 tables, and 2 bytes per entry, equalling 1/2 MiB of data.  You'd have to factor in the time taken to read the memory — cache misses etc.  The calculation is almost certainly faster, even ignoring the cost of pre-computation.